# Axios lazy post

Tags: axios, directus

I have an API I'm reading and getting 700 results. I want to POST part of this data into a Directus collection (another API). Thing is, because axios makes the posts so fast, the hosting company I'm using to host the Directus instance is immediately blocking my access...

Is there a way to lazy POST the data using axios with nodejs?

Thank you!